# RandomShuffleQueue functionality with tf.data.Dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to replace my old `RandomShuffleQueue` approach with the `tf.data.Dataset`. For some background: I am generating data on runtime, putting it in the queue and then taking it out randomly.

I don't see a way to do that with the `tf.data.Dataset`, because I would always need to generate data while I don't have a way to put the new data into the `Dataset`. Something like repeat won't help me because that just always work on the `Dataset` with the same elements that I put beforehand.

Any ideas how I get the `Queue` functionality into the `tf.data.Dataset`? Basically if I have a queue/buffer in `tf.data.DataSet`, how do I refill it with the new data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, it sounds like a perfect match for [`Dataset.from_generator()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_generator). You can add `Dataset.shuffle()` afterwards, if you would like to make a buffer and take randomly elements out of it.

Comment: Yeah that actually looks really good, thanks. Something that is missing is like a boundary for the elements the DataSet would take up, like you would be able to setg a boundary for maximum elements in a Queue.

Comment: Did you have a look `Dataset.take(count)` ? That sounds similar.